# How to attach android annotations v3+

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, android-annotations

I know that similar topics exists, but actually none of them works at 100%.

Kind of hints/script how to attach those latest `android annotations` to latest `android studio` version.

Env: Ubuntu x64, gradle 2.0, android studio 0.8.2

**Regards**

**Edit:**
The solution also works with `AndroidStudio 1.0` .

Comment: Did you check out the relevant wiki page for [Gradle configuration](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Android Studio 0.8.14.

My build.gradle for main 'app' module looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

String packageName = "mateuszklimek.aaexample"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId packageName
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.processResources.manifestFile
        resourcePackageName packageName
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.2"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.2"
}
```

Don't forget about configure top-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I have pushed example projet to [Github](https://github.com/mklimek/AndroidAnnotationsExample). 
You can build it in console by `gradlew assembleDebug`.

Comment: Cool! Just don't forget to change your "packageName" to those in AndroidManifest.